# Find Distribution After a Transformation

Tags: probability, statistics, linear-transformations

[[Here is the problem[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG7Tu.png)

I need help with part b
My attempt is I found the joint pdf then I let $$U=\frac {(X1-X2)^2}{2}$$  and $$V=X2$$. The range gonna stay from negative infinity to positive infinity for both u and v. are X2 and X1 and U and V gonna be one to one transformation? I am not sure what to do next...

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the fact that the difference of two independent normal random variables is also normally distributed?  In particular, if $$X_1 \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2), \\ X_2 \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$$
are independent, then
$$X_1 - X_2 \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_1 - \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2).$$
This property is not difficult to show; e.g., you could use generating functions:

$$M_{X_1 - X_2}(t) = M_{X_1}(t)M_{X_2}(-t) = e^{\mu_1 t + \sigma_1^2 t^2/2} e^{\mu_2 (-t) + \sigma_2^2 (-t)^2/2} = e^{(\mu_1 - \mu_2)t + (\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)t^2/2}.$$

So, with this in mind, what is the distribution of $(X_1 - X_2)/\sqrt{2}$ when $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = 0$ and $\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2 = 1$?  And now using part (a) of the problem, what is the distribution of the square of this?